# Show user information on mousehover

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, desktop-application

On Mouse-over i wish to show user information such as User Id, User Name, User Location, User Age etc. All this info would be coming from database. As well, this information would be in a rectangular block that would actually come-up on Mouse-over.

I am aware that JavaScript could be use to show div (in mouse-over) but don't know how to fetch from database?

Plus the application is a Windows Based Asp.net Application. I am not aware whether that could be possible in Windows based as i'm web based developer.

Thanks for all your inputs.

Comment: Windows Based Asp.net Application?

Comment: @Branimir: Yes that's correct.

Comment: that seems :-(.. So how could that be created?

Comment: @Romil Do you mean you're building an asp.net app that will be hosted on a Windows machine? that's pretty typical and shouldn't matter, but dropping the "Windows" name is confusing.

Comment: No, i mean its a desktop application that is built in asp.net and not the web based application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jQuery qtip plugin that can display dynamic content, see a documentation at

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/tutorials/#dynamic

and a demo at

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/loading

The url parameter should point at an aspx page that show the text that is loaded from database.